# ASP.NET5 (MVC 6) Properties out of order

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-mvc

I am fairly new to this iteration of MVC and I love it so far. However, I am several hours stuck on what I think should be a simple matter. When I scaffold out from a model, my controllers and views list my properties in alphabetical order (instead of by the order in which they are listed in the model). For example, if I have First, Last, Email, Address fields in my model, and listed in exactly that order, my controllers/views are scaffolded in this order: Address, Email, First, Last. Consequently, views look ridiculous and are not practically usable.

Any insight/help on this is deeply appreciated. Here is the relevant portion of my view template:

```
IEnumerable<PropertyMetadata> properties = Model.ModelMetadata.Properties;
foreach (var property in properties)
{
    if (property.Scaffold && !property.IsPrimaryKey && !property.IsForeignKey)
    {
    <th>
        @@Html.ActionLink("@property.PropertyName", "Index", new { sortOrder = ViewBag.@GetValueExpression(property)SortParm })
    </th>
    }
}
```

Comment: Does your Model have  data annotation with  [Display(Order = )] ?

Comment: Hi restless - thanks for taking a look. Yep, I tried that. See below:

using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

 [Display(Order = 1)]
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        [Display(Order = 2)]
        public string LastName { get; set; }

Comment: what is the order defined for Address and Email ? Do they have order or not?If no order is specified guess it defaults to zero and may be they are getting generated listed first followed by first and last name.

Comment: I have 7 properties and all are ordered starting from 0 on up. [Display(Order = ) is not changing the order for any property - they are still alphabetically listed.